# Replace AttributeError with NAN in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydicom

I am using the following code in python to read the series description from the dicom header.

```
ds = dicom.read_file(mydcmfile.dcm)
a=ds.SeriesDescription
```

However, I get the following error because this part is blank in the dicom header for this specific image:

```
AttributeError: Dataset does not have attribute 'SeriesDescription'.
```

How can I prevent this error message and replace it with NAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the exception and then treat it:

```
try:
    a = ds.SeriesDescription
except AttributeError:
   pass or something else
```

Answer (score 2):

This is generally a good way to check for an attribute that might be missing:

```
if 'SeriesDescription' in ds:
   ds.SeriesDescription = None  # or whatever you would like
```

You can also do:

```
a = ds.get('SeriesDescription')
```

which will return None if that item does not exist, or

```
a = ds.get('SeriesDescription', "N/A")
```

if you want to set your own value if the attribute does not exist.